# Python - Iterate through excel column values to split up into separate sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list

I have an excel file with different columns, and I would like to split them up into different sheets based on unique column values (in this case, the month name. So 12 sheets would be created, one for each month. I got it working when I hardcoded it without loops, but I'd rather loop it through a list to save the time.

My current output in the excel file a sheetname called 'February' with the entire dataset.

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_excel(r"PATH\data_test.xlsx", index_col = 0)
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Test3.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')
test_list = ['January', 'February']

for i in test_list:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Test3.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.loc[i]
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = i)
    print(i)
    writer.save()
```

contents of df:

```
Month      Amount      
January       125
January        32
February       12
March          70
April          48
May            98
June          110
July            7
August        124
September      63
October        93
November        6
December      118
```

Comment: can you post an example of the dataframe?  You can use `df.to_string() `

Comment: sure, I just added it

Comment: This question is not relevant to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
groups = df.groupby("Month")
with pd.ExcelWriter("my_file.xls") as writer:
    for (name, df_group) in groups:
        df_group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, this resulted in a single excel sheet named 'September with the correct value for September only.

Comment: @Iain should be fixed.